# MTF static data in table in pine script v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This is the part of the code in pinescript v5 I am stuck with :-

```
// HM

GTHM = "*** HM - Big n Small Both ***"

len_b = input.int(14, minval=1, title='Length_B', group=GTHM)
len = input.int(9, minval=1, title='Length', group=GTHM)
HMsrc = input(close, 'Source', group=GTHM)
_rsi = ta.rsi(HMsrc, len)
_rsi_b = ta.rsi(HMsrc, len_b)

// Calculate the monthly/w/d RSI for len and len_b
rsi_monthly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", _rsi)
rsi_b_monthly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", _rsi_b)

rsi_weekly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", _rsi)
rsi_b_weekly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", _rsi_b)

rsi_daily = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", _rsi)
rsi_b_daily = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", _rsi_b)

// strength price vol on M

m_wma_21 = ta.wma(rsi_monthly, 21)
m_vwma_21 = ta.vwma(rsi_monthly, 21)
m_wma_avg_21 = (m_wma_21 + m_vwma_21) / 2

m_ema_3 = ta.ema(rsi_monthly, 3)

m_wma_48 = ta.wma(rsi_b_monthly, 48)
m_vwma_48 = ta.vwma(rsi_b_monthly, 48)
m_wma_avg_48 = (m_wma_48 + m_vwma_48) / 2

m_ema_5 = ta.ema(rsi_b_monthly, 5)

// strength price vol on W

w_wma_21 = ta.wma(rsi_weekly, 21)
w_vwma_21 = ta.vwma(rsi_weekly, 21)
w_wma_avg_21 = (w_wma_21 + w_vwma_21) / 2

w_ema_3 = ta.ema(rsi_weekly, 3)

w_wma_48 = ta.wma(rsi_b_weekly, 48)
w_vwma_48 = ta.vwma(rsi_b_weekly, 48)
w_wma_avg_48 = (w_wma_48 + w_vwma_48) / 2

w_ema_5 = ta.ema(rsi_b_weekly, 5)

// strength price vol on D

d_wma_21 = ta.wma(rsi_daily, 21)
d_vwma_21 = ta.vwma(rsi_daily, 21)
d_wma_avg_21 = (d_wma_21 + d_vwma_21) / 2

d_ema_3 = ta.ema(rsi_daily, 3)

d_wma_48 = ta.wma(rsi_b_daily, 48)
d_vwma_48 = ta.vwma(rsi_b_daily, 48)
d_wma_avg_48 = (d_wma_48 + d_vwma_48) / 2

d_ema_5 = ta.ema(rsi_b_daily, 5)


// Condition for table display in green color for monthly big and small
mcond = ((rsi_monthly > m_ema_3 and m_ema_3 > m_wma_avg_21)) and (m_vwma_21 < rsi_monthly and m_vwma_21 < m_ema_3)
Bmcond = ((rsi_b_monthly > m_ema_5 and m_ema_5 > m_wma_avg_48)) and (m_vwma_48 < rsi_b_monthly and m_vwma_48 < m_ema_5)

// Condition for table display in green color for weekly big and small

wcond = ((rsi_weekly > w_ema_3 and w_ema_3 > w_wma_avg_21)) and (w_vwma_21 < rsi_weekly and w_vwma_21 < w_ema_3)
Bwcond = ((rsi_b_weekly > w_ema_5 and w_ema_5 > w_wma_avg_48)) and (w_vwma_48 < rsi_b_weekly and w_vwma_48 < w_ema_5)

// Condition for table display in green color for daily big and small

dcond = ((rsi_daily > d_ema_3 and d_ema_3 > d_wma_avg_21)) and (d_vwma_21 < rsi_daily and d_vwma_21 < d_ema_3)
Bdcond = ((rsi_b_daily > d_ema_5 and d_ema_5 > d_wma_avg_48)) and (d_vwma_48 < rsi_b_daily and d_vwma_48 < d_ema_5)

//Month
// Function to get color based on condition for small
mgetColor() =>
    mcond ? color.green : color.red

// Add data to the table
table.cell(myTable, 2, 16, "HM-S :M", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=mgetColor())

// Function to get color based on condition for big
BmgetColor() =>
    Bmcond ? color.green : color.red

// Add data to the table
table.cell(myTable, 2, 15, "HM-B :M", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=BmgetColor())

//Week
// Function to get color based on condition for small
wgetColor() =>
    wcond ? color.green : color.red

// Add data to the table
table.cell(myTable, 1, 16, "HM-S :W", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=wgetColor())

// Function to get color based on condition for big
BwgetColor() =>
    Bwcond ? color.green : color.red

// Add data to the table
table.cell(myTable, 1, 15, "HM-B :W", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=BwgetColor())

//day
// Function to get color based on condition for small
dgetColor() =>
    dcond ? color.green : color.red

// Add data to the table
table.cell(myTable, 0, 16, "HM-S :D", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=dgetColor())

// Function to get color based on condition for big
BdgetColor() =>
    Bdcond ? color.green : color.red

// Add data to the table
table.cell(myTable, 0, 15, "HM-B :D", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=BdgetColor())
```

this code is plotting data in table (from left to right) for daily weekly and monthly time frame.

this problem is - whenever I am changing time frame the entry in table is changing. If I am on monthly time frame monthly cell is showing correct but daily is wrong, if changes to daily, daily cell is showing correct but monthly is now stat showing in correct.

Table cell should be static irrespective of time frame.

I tried:

```
// Calculate the monthly/w/d RSI for len and len_b
rsi_monthly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", _rsi)
rsi_b_monthly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", _rsi_b)

rsi_weekly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", _rsi)
rsi_b_weekly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", _rsi_b)

rsi_daily = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", _rsi)
rsi_b_daily = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", _rsi_b)
```

"lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on" and imPosition and it is not seems to be working.

I am expecting table data to be static irrespective of time frame. When the chart is viewed on a monthly basis, it displays the correct information for monthly cells. However, when the chart is viewed on a daily basis, it should also show the correct information for the monthly data in monthly cell.

[image]